# Crawl td values from tr and table in jsoup without using class

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, html-table, jsoup

I am trying crawl values from td in a website using jsoup. I am new to jsoup so please tell me how to do it. Also the td or tr has no class or id to get values from so please help me on it. The html is as follows,

```html
<table cellpadding="4" id="ctl00" style="color:#333333;width:100%;"> 
 <tbody>
  <tr align="center" style="color:White;background-color:#990000;"> 
   <th scope="col"></th>
   <th scope="col"></th>
   <th scope="col"></th>
   <th scope="col"></th>
   <th scope="col"></th>
   <th scope="col"></th> 
  </tr>
  <tr align="center" style="color:#333333;background-color:#F7F6F3;"> 
   <td>1</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>4</td>
   <td>5</td>
   <td>6</td> 
  </tr>
```

I need the output as
1
2
3
4
5
6
please help me to get this.

Comment: Where do you want that output? In a javascript variable? Or do you want to send it as a string to the server side? Is that why you placed `java` as a tag? Can you be more specific?

Comment: yes i am using java here, it is good if i can store it in a string. Sorry for not being specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the required page by connecting the URL. once you have the document then look for elemnt 'td'(check the document by printing it to console if the text is in upper/lower based on that you need to use TD/td). Then get the text.

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.com").get();
Element table = document.getElementById("tableId");
Elements tds = table.getElementsByTag("td");
for(Element td : tds)
{
    System.out.println(td.text());
}
```

Comment: but there are more than one td above the given html, how to be specific to the particular td's given here.

Comment: ya there are many tables too, but i can crawl upto this table by using table id. But after that i cannot crawl to that td from which i need output.

Comment: I have edited the codes to get data from TD's of the table to which you have ID. If this is not what you are looking for, then can you paste the HTML doc you have?

Comment: Excellent thanks, i am getting the values. But here i want to store 1 in a string, 2 in another string like that all other values in a seperate string. Please help me on it.

Comment: you can do this by adding them into a list rite? so the list output would be (1,2,3,4,5,6) on iterating the list you will have all the values.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider upvoting it and accepting it as the correct answer by clicking the check mark ✔ in the middle of the vote arrows, tks

Comment: Ya sure, but they are saying my reputation should be atleast 15 to upvote. So can you please help me how to gain reputation.